# WSO2 ESB (4.9.0) / MB (3.1.0) - Could not connect to broker (Connection refused)

Tags: wso2, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I have WSO2 ESB (4.9.0) and WS02 MB (3.1.0) installed on a mounted drive on a server running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

The ESB has API endpoints configured that of which push received data to the message broker upon a post request. This process was working flawlessly until I updated the server via the typical update commands i.e. `sudo apt-get update`,
`sudo apt-get upgrade`,
`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` followed by a system reboot.

Upon rebooting and starting the MB followed by the ESB (both manually via `sh wso2server.sh`), I receive the following error from the ESB:

> ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory JMS Exception while creating connection through factory 'QueueConnectionFactory' Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>
> WARN - JMSPollingConsumer Inbound JMS endpoint unable to get a connection.

This obviously prevents the ESB sending messages to the MB. What could be causing this?

On a side note, attempting the same process via a non-root account results in the following error:

> Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. CARBON cannot execute java

Message Broker log as root (Sections are omitted):

> root@[REDACTED]:/mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/bin# sh wso2server.sh
>   JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:34,947]  WARN {org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector} -  Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at bundleresource://13.fwk1845904670/
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:34,947]  WARN {org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.StAXDialectDetector} -  Unable to determine dialect of the StAX implementation at bundleresource://13.fwk1845904670/
>    INFO {org.wso2.andes.wso2.internal.QpidBundleActivator} -  Setting BundleContext in PluginManager
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,921]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,922]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 4.4.0-141-generic, amd64
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,922]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,923]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.8.0_201
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,923]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09,Oracle Corporation
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,923]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,924]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/tmp
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:35,924]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : root, en-GB, Etc/GMT
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:36,067]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.bootup.validator.util.ValidationResultPrinter} -  Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:36,073]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.AgentHolder} -  Agent created !
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:36,093]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.thrift.internal.AgentDS} -  Successfully deployed Agent Client
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:37,935]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.jdbc.EmbeddedRegistryService} -  Configured Registry in 107ms
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,014]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.registry.core.internal.RegistryCoreServiceComponent} -  Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,078]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JDBCReporterBuilder} -  Creating JDBC reporter for Metrics with source '[REDACTED]', data source 'jdbc/WSO2MetricsDB' and 60 seconds polling period
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,079]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.util.JmxReporterBuilder} -  Creating JMX reporter for Metrics with domain 'org.wso2.carbon.metrics'
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,090]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JDBC reporter for Metrics
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,090]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.metrics.impl.reporter.AbstractReporter} -  Started JMX reporter for Metrics
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:38,327]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.UserStoreMgtDSComponent} -  Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:45,805]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ClusterBuilder} -  Clustering has been disabled
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:45,966]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:45,966]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.store.configuration.deployer.UserStoreConfigurationDeployer} -  User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:46,056]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer} -  Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v16 - file:/mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v16.mar
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:46,060]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer} -  Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v10 - file:/mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1-wso2v10.mar
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:46,334]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.andes.admin-3.1.1 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:46,368]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.andes.event.admin-3.1.1 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:46,710]  WARN {org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator} -  We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [validateAudienceRestriction]
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,285]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine} -  Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit-4.4.8 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,471]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.CarbonServerManager} -  Repository       : /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/repository/deployment/server/
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,485]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.core.internal.ds.QueueManagerServiceDS} -  Successfully created the queue manager service
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,489]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.core.internal.ds.SubscriptionManagerServiceDS} -  Successfully created the subscription manager service
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,539]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.multitenancy.eager.TenantLoadingConfig} -  Using tenant lazy loading policy...
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,549]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.permission.update.PermissionUpdater} -  Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,607]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.configuration.AndesConfigurationManager} -  Main andes configuration located at : /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/repository/conf/broker.xml
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,714]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} -  Activating Andes Message Broker Engine...
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,728]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.Broker} -  Starting Qpid using configuration : /mnt/wso2mb-3.1.0/wso2mb-3.1.0/repository/conf/advanced/qpid-config.xml
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,759]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ApplicationRegistry} -  Initialising Application Registry(org.wso2.andes.server.registry.ConfigurationFileApplicationRegistry@683c51f5)
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,782]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.plugins.PluginManager} -  Opened service trackers
>   [Broker] BRK-1001 : Startup : Version: 0.11 Build: 90784:90849
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,891]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.management.JMXManagedObjectRegistry} -  Initialising managed object registry using jplatform MBean server
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,896]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  PrincipalDatabase concrete implementation : org.wso2.carbon.andes.authentication.andes.CarbonBasedPrincipalDatabase
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,900]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  Initialised PLAIN SASL provider successfully
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,900]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  Additional SASL providers successfully registered.
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:47,900]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.security.auth.manager.PrincipalDatabaseAuthenticationManager} -  Registering UserManagementMBean
>   [Broker] MNG-1001 : Startup
>   [Broker] MNG-1004 : Ready : Using the platform JMX Agent
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,003]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSConnection} -  JDBC connection established with jndi config WSO2MBStoreDB
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,017]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl} -  Andes Context Store initialised
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,017]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesKernelBoot} -  AndesContextStore initialised with org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSAndesContextStoreImpl
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,040]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSConnection} -  JDBC connection established with jndi config WSO2MBStoreDB
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,067]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl} -  Message Store initialised
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,067]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesKernelBoot} -  Andes MessageStore initialised with org.wso2.andes.store.rdbms.RDBMSMessageStoreImpl
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:48,144]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.Andes} -  Andes API initialised.
>   INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.init.JMXServerManager} -  JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11112/jndi/rmi://localhost:10000/jmxrmi
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:49,974]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  Server           :  WSO2 Message Broker-3.1.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:49,975]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} -  WSO2 Carbon started in 16 sec
>   [2019-02-06 14:01:50,176]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} -  Mgt Console URL  : https://[REDACTED]:9444/carbon/
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:45,627]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53018)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:45,743]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.subscription.SubscriptionEngine} -  Local subscription ADDED [[REDACTED]]ID=0@[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/T=1549462005677/D=true/X=false/O=null/E=amq.direct/ET=org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.DirectExchange$1@61094da2/EUD=0/S=true
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:46,630]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53022)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:46,663]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.subscription.SubscriptionEngine} -  Local subscription ADDED [[REDACTED]]ID=1@[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/T=1549462006662/D=true/X=false/O=null/E=amq.direct/ET=org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.DirectExchange$1@61094da2/EUD=0/S=true
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:47,636]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53026)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:48,677]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53030)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:49,678]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53034)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:49,691]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.subscription.SubscriptionEngine} -  Local subscription ADDED [[REDACTED]]ID=4@[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/T=1549462009690/D=true/X=false/O=null/E=amq.direct/ET=org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.DirectExchange$1@61094da2/EUD=0/S=true
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:50,689]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53040)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:50,762]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.subscription.SubscriptionEngine} -  Local subscription ADDED [[REDACTED]]ID=5@[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/T=1549462010761/D=false/X=true/O=clientID/E=amq.topic/ET=org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.TopicExchange$1@74034026/EUD=0/S=true
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:51,719]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53044)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:52,739]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53048)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:53,784]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53052)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:54,771]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.AndesChannel} -  Channel created (ID: 127.0.0.1:53056)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:54,784]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.subscription.SubscriptionEngine} -  Local subscription ADDED [[REDACTED]]ID=9@[REDACTED]/[REDACTED]/T=1549462014782/D=true/X=false/O=null/E=amq.direct/ET=org.wso2.andes.server.exchange.DirectExchange$1@61094da2/EUD=0/S=true

ESB log as root (Sections are omitted):

> root@[REDACTED]:/mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/bin# sh wso2server.sh
>   JAVA_HOME environment variable is set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
>   CARBON_HOME environment variable is set to /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,453]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Starting WSO2 Carbon...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,458]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Operating System : Linux 4.4.0-141-generic, amd64
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,458]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,459]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Version     : 1.8.0_201
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,459]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.201-b09,Oracle Corporation
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,459]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Carbon Home      : /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,459]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator Java Temp Dir    : /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/tmp
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,460]  INFO - CarbonCoreActivator User             : root, en-GB, Etc/GMT
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,629]  WARN - ValidationResultPrinter Carbon is configured to use the default keystore (wso2carbon.jks). To maximize security when deploying to a production environment, configure a new keystore with a unique password in the production server profile.
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,639]  INFO - AgentHolder Agent created !
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:27,671]  INFO - AgentDS Successfully deployed Agent Client
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:30,171]  INFO - EmbeddedRegistryService Configured Registry in 81ms
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:30,221]  INFO - RegistryCoreServiceComponent Registry Mode    : READ-WRITE
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:32,887]  INFO - SolrClient Default Embedded Solr Server Initialized
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:33,288]  INFO - UserStoreMgtDSComponent Carbon UserStoreMgtDSComponent activated successfully.
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,096]  INFO - TaglibUriRule TLD skipped. URI: http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles is already defined
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,764]  INFO - ClusterBuilder Clustering has been disabled
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,926]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,926]  INFO - UserStoreConfigurationDeployer User Store Configuration Deployer initiated.
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,949]  INFO - JMSSender JMS Sender started
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,951]  INFO - JMSSender JMS Transport Sender initialized...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,951]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,996]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSender Pass-through HTTP Sender started...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:40,997]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Sender...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,002]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Identity Keystore from : repository/resources/security/wso2carbon.jks
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,007]  INFO - ClientConnFactoryBuilder HTTPS Loading Trust Keystore from : repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,010]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLSender Pass-through HTTPS Sender started...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,060]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : myTopicConnectionFactory initialized
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,061]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : default initialized
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,062]  INFO - JMSConnectionFactory JMS ConnectionFactory : myQueueConnectionFactory initialized
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,062]  INFO - JMSListener JMS Transport Receiver/Listener initialized...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,063]  INFO - PassThroughHttpListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,095]  INFO - PassThroughHttpSSLListener Initializing Pass-through HTTP/S Listener...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,175]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: addressing-1.6.1-wso2v14 - file:/mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/addressing-1.6.1-wso2v14.mar
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:41,178]  INFO - ModuleDeployer Deploying module: rampart-1.6.1-wso2v12 - file:/mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/client/modules/rampart-1.6.1-wso2v12.mar
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:42,074]  WARN - DefaultSchemaGenerator We don't support method overloading. Ignoring [validateAudienceRestriction]
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:42,356]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.processor-4.4.10 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:42,366]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.message.store-4.4.10 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:42,961]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: wso2carbon-sts {super-tenant}
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:42,983]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.sts-4.5.6 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,089]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: org.wso2.carbon.tryit-4.4.7 -
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,308]  INFO - CarbonServerManager Repository       : /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,442]  INFO - TenantLoadingConfig Using tenant lazy loading policy...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,453]  INFO - PermissionUpdater Permission cache updated for tenant -1234
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,511]  INFO - RuleEngineConfigDS Successfully registered the Rule Config service
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,550]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Starting ESB...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,564]  INFO - ServiceBusInitializer Initializing Apache Synapse...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,571]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using Synapse home : /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/.
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,573]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using synapse.xml location : /mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,573]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory Using server name : localhost
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,580]  INFO - SynapseControllerFactory The timeout handler will run every : 15s
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,594]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Initializing Synapse at : Wed Feb 06 14:06:43 GMT 2019
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,605]  INFO - CarbonSynapseController Loading the mediation configuration from the file system
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,608]  INFO - MultiXMLConfigurationBuilder Building synapse configuration from the synapse artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,613]  INFO - XMLConfigurationBuilder Generating the Synapse configuration model by parsing the XML configuration
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,735]  INFO - MessageStoreFactory Successfully added Message Store configuration of : [JMSMS].
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,737]  INFO - MessageStoreFactory Successfully added Message Store configuration of : [WSO2MS].
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,752]  INFO - SynapseConfigurationBuilder Loaded Synapse configuration from the artifact repository at : ././repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,756]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Loading mediator extensions...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,764]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: echo {super-tenant}
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,765]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Echo.aar - file:/mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Echo.aar
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,774]  INFO - DeploymentInterceptor Deploying Axis2 service: Version {super-tenant}
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,775]  INFO - DeploymentEngine Deploying Web service: Version.aar - file:/mnt/wso2esb-4.9.0/wso2esb-4.9.0/repository/deployment/server/axis2services/Version.aar
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,775]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying the Synapse service...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:43,777]  INFO - Axis2SynapseController Deploying Proxy services...
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:56,493]  INFO - JMXServerManager JMX Service URL  : service:jmx:rmi://localhost:11111/jndi/rmi://localhost:9999/jmxrmi
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:56,500]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Server           :  WSO2 Enterprise Service Bus-4.9.0
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:56,502]  INFO - StartupFinalizerServiceComponent WSO2 Carbon started in 33 sec
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:56,729]  INFO - CarbonUIServiceComponent Mgt Console URL  : https://[REDACTED]:9443/carbon/
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:57,206] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory JMS Exception while creating connection through factory 'QueueConnectionFactory' Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
>   [2019-02-06 14:06:57,207]  WARN - JMSPollingConsumer Inbound JMS endpoint unable to get a connection.

Answer (score 0):

The following error occurred due to your inbound endpoint trying to connect to the ActiveMQ. The default port of the ActiveMQ is 61616.

```
[2019-02-06 14:06:57,206] ERROR - JMSConnectionFactory JMS Exception while creating connection through factory 'QueueConnectionFactory' Could not connect to broker URL: tcp://localhost:61616. Reason: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused) 
[2019-02-06 14:06:57,207] WARN - JMSPollingConsumer Inbound JMS endpoint unable to get a connection.
```

I am not sure how it got changed after server updates. Anyway, you should be able to change the inbound endpoint configuration to work with the WSO2 MB 3.1.0 going through the following documentation [1].

The following error coming because of root doesn't have access to the JAVA_HOME. I mean the environment variable you have set as JAVA_HOME is not visible to the root user.

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly. CARBON cannot execute java
```

Hope above information will help to resolve the issue.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Configuring+the+JMS+Inbound+Protocol+with+WSO2+Message+Broker

Cheers!